# Prism: Commanding Delegate<T>

Tags: .net, mvvm, prism

I have a View with ViewModel as datacontext ( set in code) . In my view I have a list

```
<UserControl x:Class="ZPOS.Modules.Menu.Views.DepartmentView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Presentation.Commands;assembly=Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Presentation">
    <Grid>
<Grid.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FF9CA48A"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF90A85C" Offset="0.5"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Grid.Background>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Departments}"
                 SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush>
                                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Grid.Background>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Button Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1,1,1,1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding Path=Name}"  
                                prism:Click.Command="{Binding displayMenubyCategory}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="Auto"/>
                        <TextBlock  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"   Text="{Binding Path=Note}" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <Button Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1,1,1,1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding Path=Name}" prism:Click.Command="{Binding displayMenubyCategory}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="Auto"/>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

ViewModel

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Events;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using ZPOS.Infrastructure;
using ZPOS.Objects;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using ZPOS.Modules.Menu.Views;
using ZPOS.Contracts;
using Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Presentation.Commands;
namespace ZPOS.Modules.Menu.PresentationModels
{
    public class DepartmentViewModel : IDepartmentViewModel, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {


        private readonly IEventAggregator eventAggregator;
        private string _message;
        IMenuService service;

        public DelegateCommand<POSDepartment> displayMenubyCategory { get; private set; } 

        public string Name { get; set; }



        private ObservableCollection<POSDepartment> deptItems;
        public ObservableCollection<POSDepartment> Departments
        {
            get { return deptItems; }
            private set
            {
                if (deptItems != value)
                {
                    deptItems = value;
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("deptItems"));
                }
            }
        }

        public string Message
        {
            get { return _message; }
            set
            {
                if (_message != value)
                {
                    _message = value;
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("deptItems"));
                }
            }
        }



        public IDepartmentView View { get; private set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }





        public DepartmentViewModel(IDepartmentView deptView, IEventAggregator eventAggregator, IMenuService service)
        {
            this.View = deptView;
            this.View.Model = this;
            this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
            this.service = service;
            this.Name = "View for DepartmentModel";

            this.eventAggregator.GetEvent<DepartmentSelectionChangedEvent>().Subscribe(departmentSelectionChanged);
            displayMenubyCategory = new DelegateCommand<POSDepartment>(ExecuteCommand1, CanExecuteCommand1);

            PopulateDepartmentItems();
        }


        private void ExecuteCommand1(POSDepartment commandParameter)
        {
        }

        private bool CanExecuteCommand1(POSDepartment commandParameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void departmentSelectionChanged(POSDepartment item)
        {
            this.Message = item.Name;
        }



        private void PopulateDepartmentItems()
        {
            try
            {

                List<POSDepartment> items = service.GetAllDepartments();

                deptItems = new ObservableCollection<POSDepartment>(items);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Clicking on Button inside the listBox does not fire the command.

If I place the same button outside the list box the delage gets called.

Am I doing something wrong?

Is there a better way.  I am still new to  Prism. I also want to pass the parameter ( data context for listbox item) when command gets fired.

Thank you All

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say inside the `ListBox`, I think you're saying inside the `ItemTemplate` of the `ListBox`, right?

The `ItemTemplate` is applied to each and every item generated for the `ListBox`. Each generated item has a `DataContext` set to the data item for which it was generated. Therefore, that data item needs a property called `displayMenubyCategory` or the binding will fail. Look in your output window in Visual Studio and check for binding errors.

Moving the `Button` outside the `ListBox` implies a different `DataContext` (your view model), which means the binding will succeed and hence everything will work.

Your options include:

1. Add a `displayMenubyCategory` property to your data class, which may call into the same property of your main view model.
2. Change your binding to look outside the current `DataContext` (see [`RelativeSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource.aspx)).

Comment: @Kent- Thank you  for superfast reply. 
I will check No 2. It seems to make sense.

 No 1. when you say DataClass is it my Object (POSDepartment)?

Comment: @Kent - No 2. Did the trick - got to work it from the sample that Anderson gave. Still I will like to know how to do it using Property

Comment: He's saying your POSDepartment type might need to have a property that references the command on the parent viewModel that you can bind to.  Ex: public DelegateCommand<POSDepartment> displayMenubyCategory { get { return parentViewModel.displayMenubyCategory ; } }.  This has the advantage of not having to use the ancestor binding in your Xaml, but the disadvantage of having the very same indirection in C#.  It would allow your binding for your button to go back to a simple {Binding displayMenubyCategory}.  It's about taste more than anything.

Answer (score 3):

As Kent mentioned, you can use RelativeSource.  It's not always clear how to use it the first time, so here's a sample for you.  I think this will work (removed some button attributes for brevity):

```
<Button prism:Click.Command="{Binding 
RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.displayMenubyCategory}" />
```

This ought to do it.  It assumes you are setting DataContext to your parent ViewModel.